# How to center body on a page?

Tags: html, css, center, centering

I'm trying to center the body element on my HTML page.

[image]

Basically, in the CSS I set the body element to be `display: inline-block;` so that it is only as wide as its contents. That works fine. However, `margin: 0px auto;` doesn't center it on the page.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I want the big blue square to be centered on the page, not floating to the left like it is now.

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Should those other boxes not be inside the body?

Comment: I would suggest _not_ to centralize `body`, in fact, make a centered `div`

Comment: you should never center the body. take a look at freecsstemplates.com --- you'll designers always use divs

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Also apply text-align: center; on the html element like so:

```
html {
  text-align: center;
}
```

A better approach though is to have an inner container div, which will be centralized, and not the body.

Comment: This is exactly what was requested, why is it getting down voted? http://jsfiddle.net/gA9La/2/

Comment: I also had to set the body's display property for this to work: `body {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: @ParrisVarney Yes, that is implied (Look at OP's CSS).

Comment: I think Freakishly answer is far better than this one. No offense Madara but its answer should be the accepted one and not yours since your proposal is not the good way to center other items than texts.

Comment: @AFract The requirement was to keep the element as wide as the contents, Freakishly doesn't take that into account, at all. So while it's probably better practice to use his, it doesn't answer the question as it was asked at all.

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe I stick too much on first sentence "I'm trying to center the body element on my HTML page." :)

Comment: that also "centers" all text content of page, so not working well.

Comment: @tanaydin So you add `body { text-align: initial; }` and are good to go :)

Answer (score 37):

```
    body
    {
        width:80%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
```

This will work on most browsers, including IE.

Comment: Yeah, I like this. I didn't want to make the body have a fixed width.

Answer (score 9):

You have to specify the width to the body for it to center on the page.

[Or put all the content in the div and center it.](http://jsfiddle.net/gA9La/4/)

```
<body>
    <div>
    jhfgdfjh
    </div>
</body>​

div {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:400px;
}
```

​

Comment: Hmm.. I figured this might have been the case but.. what if I don't know the size in advance?

Comment: I tried setting the width and using a percentage but neither of them centered the body.

Comment: @SRN -- what's with the `margin` if you are testing it with just _text_ ? text can be centered with just `text-align:center` also.. check : http://jsfiddle.net/gA9La/1/

Comment: No I'm not centering just text. Most of the elements are divs.

Answer (score 3):

For those that **do** know the width, you could do something like

```
div {
     max-width: ???px; //px,%
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
}
```

I also agree about not setting **text-align:center** on the body because it can mess up the rest of your code and you might have to individually set **text-align:left** on a lot of things either then or in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Exploiting the flex layout is another option. Add to your CSS:

```
html {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Tested in Chrome, Edge, Firefox.

More Info can be found in the [refs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and hosts of online tutorials ([this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) seems handy as it is organized around container/item roles in the flex layout).