# How to center my website?

Tags: html, css

So I want to center my website, but I really don't know how to do that.
I tried `align="center"` in container div in HTML but it didn't work.

My other idea was to change widths of header and footer to `min-width` and it worked. Then I tried to set `width` of middle column (`col2`) to `min-width` to let it expand. But it didn't work too because it does nothing with `col2`'s width. Adding `float:right` to `col3` didn't work either. And now I have no idea what I should do.

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8"></meta>
  <title>Site</title>
  <link rel = "Stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container" >
    <div id = "header">header</div>
    <div id = "col1" >col1</div>
    <div id = "col2" >col2</div>
    <div id = "col3" >col3</div>
    <div id = "footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}
#container{

}
#header{
  width:1000px; /*min-width:1000px*/
  background-color:white;
  height:100px;
}
#col1{ 
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
  float:left;
}
#col2{
  width:400px; /*min-width:400px;*/
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
}
#col3{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
  float:left; /*float:right; */
}
#footer{
  clear:both;
  background-color:white;
  width:1000px; /*min-width:1000px; */
  height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center body on a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872688/how-to-center-body-on-a-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This :**

```
#container{

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: I don't know cause your answer is right and it works so thank you so much for help
But if you use 960px it makes little problem so its needed to set it for 1000px.

Comment: I have less than 15 rep or something and my votes can't be displayed

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
#divClass{
   width: 100%;     
   max-width: 1000px;     
   margin: 0 auto; 
 }
```

Comment: `center` tag is deprecated, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center